# testing asynchronous code with buttercup

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs-buttercup

I want to test [a method](https://github.com/nim-lang/nim-mode/blob/master/nim-suggest.el#L72) which takes a callback. The callback is then executed via [deferred](https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-deferred) at some later point. I have

```
(describe
  "Nimsuggest"
  (it "should suggest on a simple file"
    (with-current-buffer (find-file "tests/nimsuggest/simple.nim")
      (expect (nim-call-epc 'sug callback)))))
```

but I'm not sure what to use as the testing callback.

Comment: There is no such feature yet: https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/emacs-buttercup/issues/38